# Modular protocol design

Tags: protocol-design, provable-security

What does **modular protocol design** mean?
Why does TLS not have modular protocol design?

What protocols have modular design? (IPSec, SSH)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the definition given [there](http://eprint.iacr.org/2013/555), in a modular protocol design,

> each method or scheme used in the protocol (such as the use of nonces
>   or the application of a cryptographic schemes) has a clear goal which
>   it is proven to achieve, and sub-protocols can be replaced without
>   re-proving the security of the remaining protocol steps.

That's also the meaning used [there](http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/133).

The word *modular* is used with the meaning it has for an engineer: the ideal of building trustable complex systems from smaller trusted and well understood components, in a way such that a component can be replaced with any other having the required, stated properties. That is actually seldom done in real complex systems.

I pass as to if and why TLS, IPSec, SSH... follow, or try to follow, the modular protocol design principle, or not.

Comment: I would pass on that last question as well, it would be highly debatable - you cannot prove if something has a modular design or not. E.g. "has a clear goal" is highly subjective. If this question is asked for a test you should give your own opinion and reasons why you think it is or is not modular instead. Then the given reasoning behind your decission could be evaluated.